Monitor request and response generated by any generic library
I am trying to build a generic benchmarking solution for LLMs, where I measure latency, number of tokens, and status code of API calls to the LLM.
Since most libraries used to build LLM-based applications provide a result string as an output, I want to build a generic decorator that can just wrap a client's code and help me get the actual response body.
I have tried using proxy servers to reroute the requests, but since they will have scalability issues, I would prefer to use something else.
@wrap_func()
def ask(prompt)

    #client code to fetch output

    return result

